# Set up a dynamic array

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to build an array depending on the size of a list. Therefore I try the following:

```
Range("D3").Select
Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

Dim totalRows As Integer
totalRows = (x.Rows.Count) - 1

Dim strCDRack(0 To totalRows) As String
```

This however gives me a compile error. Thats strange cause when I replace totalRows by 3 it does work

```
Range("D3").Select
Set x = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown))

Dim totalRows As Integer
totalRows = (x.Rows.Count) - 1

Dim strCDRack(0 To 3) As String
```

Any thoughts on how I can make this working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically answered your question yourself already ;) (about the reason of the error, not the solution of course). You can't `Dim` arrays with variable dimensions (as it says in the error message, more or less).

Use

```
Dim strCDRack() As String
ReDim strCDRack(0 To totalRows)
```